# How to create 2 incompatible number-like types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typing

I've been trying to figure out how to create 2 mutually-incompatible number-like/integer types in TS.

For example, in the code below, height and weight are both number-like, but the concept of adding them together or treating them equivalently is nonsensical and should be an error.

```
type height = number; // inches
type weight = number; // pounds
var a: height = 68;
var b: weight = operateScale(); // Call to external, non-TS function, which returns a weight.
console.log(a+b); // Should be an error.
```

Is there a way to create 2 types which are both numbers, but are not compatible with each other?

---

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments section, this behavior appears to be analogous to haskell's `newtype` behavior.

---

EDIT2: After several hours of poking the problem with a pointy stick, I managed to reach an answer, which I have posted below.

Comment: In Haskell, that would be a `newtype` as opposed to a *type alias*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, yes, that looks like what I would want in TS.

Comment: Googling for "newtype typescript" yields some libraries.

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible right now. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)

Comment: @Gerrit0 I've just done it. Answer is below.

Answer (score 11):

The closest thing to a `newtype` in TypeScript is to create a new "nominal" type (TypeScript doesn't have nominal types but there are workarounds like [branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)) and create a value constructor and a field accessor function which just uses type assertions in the implementation.  For example:

```
interface Height { 
  __brand: "height"
}
function height(inches: number): Height {
  return inches as any;
}
function inches(height: Height): number {
  return height as any;
}

interface Weight { 
  __brand: "weight"
}
function weight(pounds: number): Weight {
  return pounds as any;
}
function pounds(weight: Weight): number {
  return weight as any;
}

const h = height(12); // one foot
const w = weight(2000); // one ton
```

The types `Height` and `Weight` (sorry, can't bring myself to give new types a lowercase name) are treated as distinct types by the compiler.  The `height()` function is a `Height` value constructor (takes a `number` and returns a `Height`), and the `inches()` function is its associated field accessor (takes a `Height` and returns a `number`), and `weight()` and `pounds()` are the analogous functions for `Weight`.   And all of those functions are just identity functions at runtime.  So JavaScript treats them as pure numbers with a bit of function-call overhead that's hopefully optimized away by a good compiler, and if you're *really* worried about that overhead, you can do the assertions yourself:

```
const h = 12 as any as Height;
const w = 2000 as any as Weight;
```

---

Now you have distinct named types you can use so you don't accidentally use a `Height` where a `Weight` is needed or vice versa.  But, just like with a `newtype`, the compiler will not treat these as a `number`.  Yes, you could make `Height` and `Weight` subtypes of `number` (via intersection types), but that's probably a mistake: the arithmetic operators like `+` are able to operate on `number` values and if both `h` and `w` are subtypes of `number`, then `h + w` will not be an error.  And if `h` and `w` are *not* subtypes of `number`, then `h + h` will be an error.  And you can't change that, since TypeScript does not let you alter the type declarations of operators [the way it does with functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).  I prefer to prevent both `h + h` and `h + w` from compiling, so the `Height` and `Weight` types are not `number`s.  Instead, let's create our own `add()` function that behaves how you want:

```
type Dimension = Height | Weight;

function add<D extends Dimension>(a: D, b: D): D {
  return ((a as any) + (b as any)) as any;
}
```

The `add()` function accepts *either* two `Height` or two `Weight` parameters, and returns a value of the same type.  Actually, with the above it's still possible to pass in something like `Height | Weight` as `D`, so if you're really serious about locking it down you can use overloads instead:

```
function add(a: Height, b: Height): Height;
function add(a: Weight, b: Weight): Weight;
function add(a: any, b: any): any {
  return a+b;
}
```

And, behold:

```
const twoH = add(h, h); // twoH is a Height
const twoW = add(w, w); // twoW is a Weight
const blah = add(h, w); // error, Height and Weight don't mix
```

---

So we're almost done.  For your external `measureScale()` function you'd just declare the return type to be a `Weight`:

```
declare function measureScale(): Weight;

var a = height(68);
var b = measureScale();
```

And verify the intended result:

```
console.log(add(a,b)); // err
console.log(add(a,a)); // okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://tsplay.dev/w1yBYw)

Answer (score 1):

So, after banging my head against the wall for several hours, I managed to come up with this:

```
class height extends Number {}
class weight extends Number {}
```

By sub-classing the `Number` class, Typescript allows you to create distinct numeric types.

And then you can go and use the variables as specified above.

```
var a: height = 68;
var b: weight = 184;
console.log(a+b); // Should be an error.
```

The issue that I run into is that this also returns an error:

```
console.log(a+a); // Should NOT be an error.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to stop you from saying `height = weight`.